# PowerBI DAX error: comparing values of type text with values of type integer

Tags: powerbi, comparison, dax

I need help with a PowerBI error. I cannot display any data because of this error I've been receiving from DAX: dax comparison operations do not support comparing values of type text with values of type integer.

It appears that the error is in this part of the formula:

```
    FILTER('tgv vDimWorkspaceArea', 'tgv vDimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey && 'tgv vDimWorkspaceArea'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey),
    FILTER('tgv vDimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty', 'tgv vDimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey && 'tgv vDimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey)
```

I have checked the formats of the "ValidToKey" and "ValidFromKey", they are both in the format of Whole number in the table (e.g. 20220421).
Any ideas where else I should look?

Thank you

Comment: From the information you provided, you will need to change the datatype by entering the power query end, right-click on the column and select "change type" on the drop down list.  The value "20220421" looks like a date combo. so change it to date. let's see its response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check steps:

1.

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'),
    'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'[ComfortCO2] <> "null"
    ,FILTER(
        'dm DimWorkspaceArea'
        ,'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey 
        && 'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey
    )
    ,FILTER(
        'dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'
        ,'dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey 
        && 'dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey)
)
```

2. 

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'),
    'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'[ComfortCO2] <> "null"
)
```

3. 

```
 COUNTROWS(
      FILTER(
         'dm DimWorkspaceArea'
         ,'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey 
          && 'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey
      )
 )
```

4. 

---

```
  COUNTROWS(
       FILTER(
          'dm DimWorkspaceArea'
          ,-- 'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey 
           --&& 
          'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey
       )
  )
```

5. 

```
 COUNTROWS(
      FILTER(
         'dm DimWorkspaceArea'
         ,'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey 
          -- && 'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey
      )
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

no it's not possible to get blank. The ValidTo and ValidFrom keys are in the format of date. I tried the rest of the formula via trial and error and it was working. When I inserted these filter queries it stopped working.

Here is the rest of the formula:

```
Index = 
VAR MinSelectedDateKey = MIN('Calendar'[DateKey])
VAR MaxSelectedDateKey = MAX('Calendar'[DateKey])
RETURN
(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'),
        FILTER(
            'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new',
            'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'[ComfortCO2] = "High" && 'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'[ComfortHumidity] = "High" 
            || 'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'[ComfortCO2] = "High" && 'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'[ComfortHumidity] = "Medium" 
        ),
        FILTER('dm DimWorkspaceArea', 'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey && 'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey),
        FILTER('dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty', 'dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey && 'dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey)
    ) + 0
)  /  
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'),
    'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'[ComfortCO2] <> "null",
    FILTER('dm DimWorkspaceArea', 'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey && 'dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey),
    FILTER('dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty', 'dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'[ValidFromKey] <= MaxSelectedDateKey && 'dm DimDeviceWorkspaceAreaParty'[ValidToKey] >= MinSelectedDateKey)
)
*100
```

Comment: It would be better to add it to the question section. did you change the key data type from int to date? I'll try to check the code today later.

Comment: Yes, the columns are already in the date format.

Comment: HI, which part of RETURN doesn't work both CALCULATE()?

Comment: the FILTER parts with datekeys: ValidTo and ValidFrom

Comment: Your syntax looks Ok, you can just  reduce it a little bit, but it looks good. I ask you to check  both `CALCULATE()`  to be sure that your estimation about `FILTER` is correct. So, you have the second `CALCULATE()`  which is easer to analyze. Can you check it separately without the first one and without *100 ? If it doesn't work, then check without `CALCULATE()` : `COUNTROWS('dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new')` and filters like `COUNTROWS(FILTER())`. IF `COUNTROWS(FILTER())` returns rows then check  only with the first FILTER() then SECOND(). I hope you understand the way how to find the problem.

Comment: As idiots didn't let me use the answer window, so let continue here in comments.

Comment: So only number 2 worked and returned values. The rest did not work.

Comment: COUNTROWS(DimWorkspaceArea)? to be sure that your current context returns the table

Comment: Then what is the value for MAX('dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey]) if the table exists in the context

Comment: No, this worked only:  COUNTROWS('dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'),
    'dm FactEnviroData_Agr60_new'[ComfortCO2] <> "null". 
The MAX value for ValidFromKey is 20220503.

Comment: and the value for MaxSelectedDateKey and MIN('dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey])?

Comment: the min is -1 and max is 99991231. Do you think this could be an issue? -1 is an integer, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Can you check once more INT(MinSelectedDateKey) and INT(MAX('dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey])). What are values for them?

Comment: for MIN it returns 20220401 and for MAX various datekeys ranging from 20220412 to 20220503

Comment: Didn't get the point. In one calculation it can be 1 max.

Comment: ah sorry, it returns TRUE.

Comment: So you got the error source. Do you see the reason for the TRUE value. It can be that the column is a text.

Comment: Try MAX(VALUE('dm DimWorkspaceArea'[ValidFromKey]))

Comment: and let me know if you fixed the problem